# Adding new records to a dataframe for variables extracted from the same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, copy, reshape

I am trying to consolidate variables in a data set.
I have something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


data = np.array([[160,90,'skirt_trousers', 'tight_comfy'],[180,100,'trousers_skirt', 'long_short']])
dford = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['height','size','order', 'preference'])
```

[image]

and am trying to get it to something like this:

```
dataForTarget = np.array([['o1',160,90,'skirt', 'tight'],['o2', 180,100,'trousers', 'long'],['o1',160,90,'trousers', 'comfy'],['o2', 180,100,'skirt', 'short']])
Targetdford = pd.DataFrame(dataForTarget, columns = ['orderID','height','size','order', 'preference'])
```

[image]

As a first step, I have extracted as much data as possible from the strings,
then cleaned them:

```
variables = dford.columns.tolist()
variables.append('ord1')
secondord = dford.order.str.extractall (r'_(.*)')
secondord = secondord.unstack()
secondord.columns = secondord.columns.droplevel()
dford1 = dford.join(secondord)
dford1. columns = variables
dford1.order = dford1.order.str.replace(r'(_.*)','')


variables = dford1.columns.tolist()
variables.append('pref1')
secondpref = dford.preference.str.extractall (r'_(.*)')
secondpref = secondpref.unstack()
secondpref.columns = secondpref.columns.droplevel()
dford2 = dford1.join(secondpref)
dford2. columns = variables
dford2.order = dford2.order.str.replace(r'(_.*)','')
```

Which gets me here:
[image]

At this stage I am at a loss on how to add these new information as observations (in rows).

The best I could come up with follows, but fails as the index contains
duplicate entries. But even if it did not fail, I suspect it would 
only be useful if I were trying to fill in missing values.

But I got nowhere.

```
dford3 = dford2.rename(columns = {'ord1': 'order', 'pref1': 'preference'})
dford3= dford3.stack()
dford3= dford3.unstack()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) for new DataFrame and add to original by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = pd.concat([dford.pop('order').str.split('_', expand=True).stack().rename('order'), 
                dford.pop('preference').str.split('_', expand=True).stack().rename('preference')], axis=1)


dford = (dford.join(df.reset_index(level=1)).rename_axis('orderID')
              .reset_index()
              .sort_values(['level_1','orderID'])
              .drop('level_1', 1)
              .reset_index(drop=True)
              .assign(orderID = lambda x: 'o' + x['orderID'].add(1).astype('str')))

print (dford)
  orderID height size     order preference
0      o1    160   90     skirt      tight
1      o2    180  100  trousers       long
2      o1    160   90  trousers      comfy
3      o2    180  100     skirt      short
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) + [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).
concatenate the resulting dataframes with [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to create the `Hight` and `Size` Series:

```
df=pd.concat([df.T for df in dford[['order','preference']].apply(lambda x: x.str.split('_',expand=True),axis=1)]).rename_axis(index='OrderID').reset_index() 

df['height']=df['OrderID'].map(dford['height'])
df['size']=df['OrderID'].map(dford['size'])
print(df)

   OrderID     order preference height size
0        0     skirt      tight    160   90
1        1  trousers      comfy    180  100
2        0  trousers       long    160   90
3        1     skirt      short    180  100
```

---

finally add one to the `OrderID` column and add the character `o`

```
df['OrderID']='o'+df['OrderID'].add(1).astype('str')
print(df)

  OrderID     order preference height size
0      o1     skirt      tight    160   90
1      o2  trousers      comfy    180  100
2      o1  trousers       long    160   90
3      o2     skirt      short    180  100
```